# How to search and Display rows from table for two or multiple value

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in sql database as below

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Date</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Time<br></th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Title</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">Contact<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2017</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">5:45</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">The Study of Galaxy and star formation</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">NA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2018</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">5:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Study Properties of Magnetic Properties of Earth Poles</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">NA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2019</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">6:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Solar Radiation and Global Temperature Rate</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">NA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2020</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">6:12</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Medical Science and advance Laser Technology</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">NA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using sql search wildcard as below to return and display row   that contains any single value from search bar as below

```
$query = "select Date,Time,Title,Contact from book_info where  Title like '%$search%'
```

It works fine . But when user enters two or multiple keywords in search bar like Galaxy star, Then it should Display second row similarly if user Types
Science  Laser then it should display Last row.

How can I do this.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server? Please remove the redundant tag.

Comment: If the user enters "Science Laser" then you would need to change that to "Science%Laser" for SQL Server to allow other characters in between the typed words.

Comment: @DaleBurrell so should I used this instead "where  Title like '%$search%%%$search%'"  where %$search% for first word and % inbetween and next %$search% for next word?

Comment: Assuming its SQL-Server you use a single % as a wildcard e.g. "%Science%Laser%" https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to take what the user entered and check for books that contain all he words in the same order as was written by the user, replace the spaces with % (pseudocode; I don't do php):

```
$search = replace($search, " ", "%")
```

This will run a query of:

```
WHERE title like '%science%laser%'
```

This WON'T find a book called "lasers: a science breakthrough"

---

If you want to return all results matching all words you'll have to split the string up into individual words and add multiple clauses to your AND so you end up with a query that looks like:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM books
WHERE 1=1
  AND title like '%science%'
  AND title like '%laser%'
```

This will find a book called "medical science advance laser tech" and it will find a book called "lasers: a science breakthrough"

I recommended to put the 1=1 in the query because it's useless but it makes the query easier to build. Here is a pseudocode:

```
words = stringsplit(search, " ")
sql = "select whatever from books where 1=1 "
param = 1
for each(word in words){
  sql = sql + "and title like @p$param"
  parameters.add("@p$param", "%$word%")
  param = param +1
}
database.query(sql,parameters)
```

This produces syntactically correct sql without any complex "if it's the first word then don't put the and ..."

Lastly please have a read of http://bobby-tables.com - the way I've built the sql search command above absolutely should be the approach you take when including values supplied by the user, into an sql string.

Just plain up taking what they gave you and putting it into your sql puts a massive security hole in your application and gives the end user pretty much full control of your database. Do not do that in practice under any circumstance. The above code is an indicator of how you can use a loop to:

```
Add a named parameter to a database query string
Give the parameter a value 
Run the query with the parameters
```

It's pseudocode, representing a concept. If you don't know how to parameterize a db query in your chosen programming language, and bobby-tables doesn't tell you(maybe they have examples), then the very next google search you make should be "how do I parameterize a sql query in " and never write another query that isn't parameterized